# Why is Elizabeth's last name "Greenhough-Smith"?

Tags: dimension-w

Elizabeth Greenhough-Smith is the daughter of Julian Smith (i.e. Loser) and Sophia Tyler.

Who is "Greenhough", and why does Elizabeth have her name, rather than, say, her mother's?

Answer (score 1):

His full name isn't Julian Smith, it's Julian Tyler Smith, so I assume Greenhough is Sophia's maiden name.

His name tag reveals that he has Tyler on his name:

[image]

I'm pretty sure his name was shown as "Julian Tyler Smith" at some point on either the manga or anime, but I can't remember when.

Comment: Please provide proofs on your claim. Was it mentioned anywhere in the manga or anime? What are the clues that lead you to such assumption?

Comment: Edited my post to include some evidence.